# QEMU load average vs cpu count

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, cpu-usage, qemu, vcpu

When I configure more CPU cores, the load average in my Guest OS as shown by `top` also increases linearly.

I'm trying to understand why this happens, because I expected either the opposite or at least for it to stay the same. As load average should be calculated independantly of the amount of cores?

For example, with 4 vCPU using `-smp 4` the load average of my guest is around 2.60. If I decrease to 2 vCPU, the load average drops to around 1.30.

Does anyone have a logical explanation why this happening?